# Spring data elastic | search after query

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using ElasticsearchRepository.I am looking is there any way to perform search after query using this.I have checked spring data docs but didnt find the way.Can anybody help on this.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? what have you tried and what does not work?

Comment: I want to do search after a query of elastic search using Spring's ElasticsearchRepository. But didnt find a method to do so